# 2 submits with same validation?

Tags: users, forms

I am modifying user_pass so that it also has an option to resend a user's activation email.

```
if($form_id=='user_pass'){
    $form['name']['#title'] = 'Email Address';
    $form['actions']['submit'] = array();
    $form['actions']['submit_reset'] = array(
        '#value' => t('Reset Password'),
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#attributes' => array('class' => array('btn-primary', 'btn'))

    );

    //resend button
     $form['actions']['submit_resend'] = array (
        '#value' => t('Resend Activation Email'),
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#submit' => '_mymodule_resend_activation', //gives invalid argument on foreach
        '#attributes' => array('class' => array('btn-primary', 'btn'))
    );
}
```

This doesn't seem to work bc I get an invalid argument for a foreach when I set the submit property for the resend button. But the reset functionality is exactly as I want it. Is there a way I can use the same validation for both submits and have a custom handler for the second one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`#submit`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7#submit_property) and [`#validate`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7#validate) each need to be an array:

```
$form['actions']['submit_resend'] = array (
  '#value' => t('Resend Activation Email'),
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#submit' => array('_mymodule_resend_activation'),
  '#validate' => array('_mymodule_form_validate'),
  '#attributes' => array('class' => array('btn-primary', 'btn'))
);
```

As far as I know there aren't any limits on the number of elements that can share the same validation callback.

Comment: Beat me to it :)

Comment: If you need to add a different validation function(s) for this second button, add `#validate` property as well (as an array, see `#submit` above). 
+1 :)

Comment: @rooby You an I seem to be answering the same things at the same time - you've beaten me to it a few times already today ;)